# Construct a java.util.List from a java.util.Set in Scala

Tags: java, list, scala, set, scala-collections

I would like to create a java List based on another java Collection eg. Set in Scala.

Why is this not possible? I get a required: scala.this.Int error.

```
val in: java.util.Set[String] = new java.util.HashSet()
val out : java.util.List[String] = new java.util.ArrayList(in)
```

This worked however, but doesn't feel right:

```
val in: java.util.Set[String] = new java.util.HashSet()
val out: List[String] = new java.util.ArrayList()

out.addAll(in.asInstanceOf[java.util.Set[String]])
```

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the answers!

I noticed that if the Set's type was unspecified (no Generics used), this works too:

    val out: List[String] = new ArrayList[String](int.asInstanceOf[Set[String]])

Comment: Thanks for the question - by trying to answer it I learnt a lot about Scala. BTW, if someone answers you it is polite to upvote or accept their answer. (I didn't answer, but I was grateful to those who did)

Comment: Filed in trac https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/ticket/2119

Comment: Thanks for the pointer Nick! My first time around here :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to explicitly pass the ArrayList type variable.

This works fine:

```
val in = new java.util.HashSet[String]
val out = new java.util.ArrayList[String](in)
```

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
val in: java.util.Set[String] = new java.util.HashSet()
val out : java.util.List[String] = new java.util.ArrayList[String](in)
```

I assume the problem is somehow related to type erasure, as ArrayList is not parametrized as a Scala array would be, but, rather, it's an existential type. This is probably making the type inference impossible.